# RLC circuit magnitude of the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, passive-networks

I found a lecture MIT, [about RLC circuit](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/resonance_qfactr.pdf). 
I think there is an error in the formula 1.1.
After all the transformations, I can not get the same formula...
My decision path is the same as in this [document](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~gan/teaching/summer04/Lec4.pdf).

Tell me please how they get formula 1.1?

[image]

Comment: I'm sure that \$R\$ label above the inductor is a typo.

Comment: KingDuken, I agree with you. But in calculations they applied L.

Comment: Anyways, they got the transfer function by solving for \$V_R\$ and dividing it by the \$V_S\$. As obvious as that might sound, it shouldn't be _that_ complicated. Determining how much you know about circuit analysis can help you see how \$V_R\$ was found using a voltage divider. Once you find \$V_R\$ (which by the way, will contain \$V_S\$) divide by \$V_S\$. Then algebraically reduce the answer.

Comment: I solved through a divider. 
I got exactly the same as here : https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~gan/teaching/summer04/Lec4.pdf

Comment: It looks like the denominator has the 1st term reversed and maybe it is \$ (\omega^2LC-1)^2\$

Comment: I looked at the document you linked and see that their formula (when re-arranged) is exactly what 1.1 implies. What is it in particular that you are having problems with. Bear also in mind that this is probably best suited to a math site as generally this has little to do with EE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because HW needs an attempt at a solution

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: Dave, this is not a homework assignment! Initially, I was trying to understand how the smd inductance differs from the inductance with the air core. I noticed that the inductance with an air core has a high quality factor.I began to read documents about Q-factor. I really love fundamental knowledge. And so I began to study the document above.

Unfortunately, my mathematical knowledge is not so strong. (But I am improving myself, doing exercises in higher mathematics and watching lectures :)  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the voltage divider: \$\frac{V_R}{V_S}=\frac{R}{R+j\omega L-\frac{j}{\omega C}}=\frac{\omega CR}{\omega CR+j\omega^2CL-j}=\frac{\omega CR}{\omega CR+j(\omega^2CL-1)}\$

Then take the magnitude.